# Adding new app in django installed app gives error populate() isn't reentrant for IIS

Tags: python, django, iis, django-settings

First of all I have seen all SO threads related to problem of `error populate() isn't reentrant` but problem I'm facing is different among them.

**Things I want to clear first:**

> 1. My Django app works perfectly on **IIS Server** with only my app registered in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`of project.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'MyDjangoWebApp.app',]
```

> 2. When I add new app in my `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` of project it works perfectly in Django **Local Server** (E.g Server created and hosted by Pycharm)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',

'Busisoft_Document_Extraction_Web.app',
// Newly added app which I installed through PIP
'widget_tweaks']
```

> 3.But when I host same project from **IIS server**, it gives me

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main
env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path)
File "c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in 
read_wsgi_handler
handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER"))
File "c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\wfastcgi.py", line 605, in 
get_wsgi_handler
handler = handler()
File "c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
django.setup(set_prefix=False)
File "c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\venv\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 81, in populate
raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

*Interesting is that if I remove that extra app IIS works perfectly.*

**My web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add name="DjangoIISHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\venv\Scripts\python.exe|c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
  <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp" />
  <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()" />
  <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="c:\server\MyDjangoWebApp\wfastcgi.log" />
  <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="Busisoft_Document_Extraction_Web.settings" />
  <add key="WSGI_RESTART_FILE_REGEX" value=".*((\.py)|(\.config))$" />
</appSettings>
```

**My System Configuration**

1. Windows 10
2. IIS Server 10
3. Python 3.5 (32-bit)
4. Django 2.1.7

Comment: What is the result of `python manage.py check` in your IIS server?

Comment: How to do it in IIS server?? How it is related to IIS server. I run this command through Terminal in project. And it gives me 'System check identified no issues (0 silenced).'

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it on IIS server. Here I mean by IIS server is the place where you hosted the project/the place where you got the error

Comment: Okay. No I got no error for that command

Comment: @ParikshitChalke - were you ever able to find a solution for this problem? I'm running into a very similar problem and can't find a way around it short of creating a separate virtual directory under my IIS site

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in past and it was on ubuntu server. Please check your imports in view file. In case the imports are relative import (i.e. from .models import MyModel) then add following line at top of your file.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Delete pycache and restart the service.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I don't totally get your answer. First thing is that I use this new app directly in templates. i.e {% load widget_tweaks %}. Second thing the error is not Run-Time but Compile-Time, means whenever I launch my app it directly gives error.